# How to run external programs asynchronously in Perl?

Tags: perl, asynchronous

I need to do this:

1. Run program1 (async)
2. Run program2 (sync)
3. Remember return code of program2
4. Kill program1

Comment: `IPC::Open3` or `fork(); exec()`;

Comment: @jordanm, Why would you replicate the 100s of lines of IPC::Open3 by using fork+exec directly. Even IPC::Open3 might be too low level compared to IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run.

Comment: @alkedr, Depends on whether you need to feed them input, capture their output, etc.

Comment: @ikegami, no, I don't need to capture anything except return code of program2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
use IPC::Run qw( start run );
my $prog1_h = start [ $prog1, @progs1_args ];
run [ $prog2, @progs2_args ];
my $prog2_exit_code = $? >> 8;
$prog1_h->finish();
```